# C# OpenFileDialog - exception when no files are chosen

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, null, openfiledialog

I am trying to work out on this error, when no files are chosen the program obviously goes to do next step although it shouldn't. I have tried:

```
if (fileToCheck != null)
```

but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

```
private void Mail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
            spamText.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);               
    }


    string[] fileToCheck = { openFileDialog.FileName };

    Splitter(fileToCheck);
    mail = tempDict;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_? Which exception are you talking about?

Comment: How does that code even compile?  `ShowDialog` does not return a bool.  Please provide code that actually compiles.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway in WPF it compiles perfectly

Comment: I stand corrected.  I wonder why MS made the WPF OpenFileDialog have a different return value than it's WinForms counterpart?  If you will make some edit to the question, I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was on the right track.

But checking `if (fileToCheck != null)` is not enough, since when no file is selected, `openFileDialog.FileName` contains empty string, not null.

So you can use `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileToCheck))` check.

Another way - just put the code around `fileToCheck` which is currently outside of `openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true` condition just inside of it. It looks more logical, since if file not selected, this condition will not be hit and you don't need to proceed with additional check.

So your code could look like

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        spamText.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);               
        Splitter(new [] {fileName});
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to call `File.Exists(fileToCheck)`

Comment: If I would make it inside of `if` statement, should I include `&& openFileDialog.FileName.Trim() != string.Empty` ?

Comment: Just use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `FileName` is not Empty before you call `Splitter`. You can use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace In the Splitter you can use File.Exists to find out if file exists.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileToCheck))
{
    string[] fileToCheck = { openFileDialog.FileName };
    Splitter(fileToCheck);
    mail = tempDict;
}
else
{
    //Do something
}
```